# Using sub/gsub to swap a string and remove brackets

Tags: r

I have the following string (where the format will always be the same but the place names will not), and I wish to swap the order of the places (and remove the brackets) like so;

```
team
Newcastle United, (Premier League)
```

Trying to get;

```
team
Premier League, Newcastle United
```

To do this I think I'm quite close just struggling with the special characters. So far I have the following where I am trying to say everything up until we see a bracket is where we split and then we swap them. Can then just gsub out the brackets on another line

```
gsub("(.+)\\([A-z]+\\)", "\\2 \\1", team)
```

*string will stay in the same format apart from the comma which is not always there

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
txt <- c("Newcastle United, (Premier League)")

gsub("([^,]+), \\(([^)]+)\\)", "\\2 \\1", txt)
#> [1] "Premier League Newcastle United"
```

To explain: we have two captured groups..

- `([^,]+)` match everything except a comma multiple times
- `\\(([^)]+)\\)` a group within parenthesis that matches everything except a closing parenthesis multiple times

we then replace the whole match with the second and first captured group.

Comment: it seems to work the same with `(.+)` replacing the `([^,]+)`s. Don't think it would make a difference, seeing as you're looking for it at the end anyway?

Comment: Sorry probably should have mentioned this so completely my fault but I wont always have a comma to use here but everything else will stay as a constant

Comment: gsub("(.+)(\\(.+\\))", "\\2 \\1", team) will swap the team in front of the league then the brackets and comma can be gsubed out on another line

Comment: You can include a questionmark after the comma so that it becomes (with Mark's comment) `(.+),? \\(([^)]+)\\)`.